# get only alphanumeric rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've column with data

```
CLARK
KING
MILLER
SMITH, $800 .00
JONES, $2975.00
SCOTT, $3000.00
ADAMS, $1100.00
FORD, $3000.00
ALLEN30  
WARD30  
MARTIN30  
BLAKE30  
TURNER30  
JAMES30
```

I'want only alphanumeric rows means

```
SMITH, $800 .00
JONES, $2975.00
SCOTT, $3000.00
ADAMS, $1100.00
FORD, $3000.00
```

except this rows all rows should be included?

How can i get this?

Comment: ALLEN30, WARD30, etc would be considered alphanumeric...you need to key on the format of the data.  Can you assume that the records you want to look at contain an Alphabetic string followed by a comma, then a dollar amount?

Comment: what is your table structure? are those strings "SMITH, $800 .00" all in one column? or are they multiple columns/tables?

Comment: @Brett yeah all in one column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx):

```
DECLARE @test table(col varchar(30));
INSERT INTO @test
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'CLARK' UNION ALL SELECT 'KING' UNION ALL SELECT 'MILLER' UNION ALL SELECT 'SMITH, $800 .00' UNION ALL SELECT 'JONES, $2975.00' UNION ALL SELECT 'SCOTT, $3000.00' UNION ALL SELECT 'ADAMS, $1100.00' UNION ALL SELECT 'FORD, $3000.00' UNION ALL SELECT 'ALLEN30' UNION ALL SELECT 'WARD30' UNION ALL SELECT 'MARTIN30' UNION ALL SELECT 'BLAKE30' UNION ALL SELECT 'TURNER30' UNION ALL SELECT 'JAMES30')AS T(Spalte)
```

`Patindex` returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a specified expression. Since i've used a pattern that matches any non-alphanumeric ([^ Wildcard - Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188342.aspx)), this returns only records which  contain only alphanumeric characters (+ white-spaces):

```
SELECT col 
FROM   @test
WHERE  PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%',col) = 0
```

Result:

```
CLARK
KING
MILLER
ALLEN30
WARD30
MARTIN30
BLAKE30
TURNER30
JAMES30
```

Comment: what this pattern `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'` does?

Comment: I tried `SELECT data FROM Vv
where patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%',data) = 0
` but it only gives `CLARK
KING
MILLER` can you tell me where the problem?

Comment: @user1095881: Patindex returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a specified expression. Since i've used a pattern that matches any non-alphanumeric ([^ Wildcard - Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188342.aspx)), this returns only records which  contain only alphanumeric characters. **Edit** I've used your sample data and - as you can see - it works.

Comment: @user1095881: Maybe there are white-spaces in your table, i've edited my answer to show how to allow them in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where len((replace(your_col, '$', '')) != len(your_col)
```

Comment: `$` could be another character also this is not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of your problem is that the table design is poor - columns should be atomic and contain only one type of item. If the numeric were in a separate column (the correct design) you could use several techniques to return rows which had the numeric populated (e.g. WHERE NOT NULL, as a simple example).

In your case, assuming you don't want to change the table design, you could use a LIKE clause to find rows where the column contains '$'. This is hugely inefficient though, and I suggest it without endorsing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement similar to:

```
SELECT colname = CASE CaseName
    WHEN '%$%' THEN colname
    END
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think table structure could be improved for speed, but given what we have...

```
Select * from [table]
where [column] like '%$%'
```

or did you want the rows without the '$'?

```
Select * from [table]
where [column] not like '%$%'
```

this is of course assuming that you only want the rows with the dollar sign.

If you were to have something like this:

```
[Name] [Dollars]
SMITH   800.00
```

Then you could query like so:

```
Select [Name], [Dollars]
From [table]
Where [Dollars] is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col
from tab
where PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%',col)=0
```